# How to download wikipedia images dump

Tags: wikipedia, wiki, wikipedia-api, wikimedia, wikimedia-dumps

I am trying to make offline version of wikipedia. But the problem is I am not able to download image dump of wikipedia. All they provide is SQL with only meta image info, there is not actula images anywhere.

[Dump Link](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/mirrors.html)

Also, I am using wikimedia to run wikipedia on local server. Any help how to download images or is there other way to download images/content on local.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to look at [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/) which provides a [complete offline Wikipedia](http://www.kiwix.org/downloads/) experience with thumbnails.  (~75 GiB)

The reason there isn't any tarball because its huge.  The "Fair Use" media (low resolution copyrighted images such as poster, album art, etc.) for English Wikipedia [is 162 GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MediaStatistics).  We also have a lot of media on Wikimedia Commons, [153 TiB](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:MediaStatistics), mostly unused.

Limiting to only what's necessary for English Wikipedia, you'll need to download **5.1 TiB** from 4,525,268 non-multimedia files.

Comment: But can we host it on local server and access this from other network devices

Comment: Kiwix claims for $100 of hardware (Raspberry Pi 3, 128 GB MicroSD) that it can provide a Wikipedia Wi-Fi Hotspot, serving a 25 student classroom.  The project is also supported in various ways by the Wikimedia Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing. Old dumps from 2012 are available [on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/wikimedia-mediatar).

Comment: you can do that using mediawiki. It allows you to install wikipedia like server on machine. After installation you have to import the dumps. I am able to use mediawiki with only text part. I was stuck in Image part

Comment: As I just said, there is no image dump.

Answer (score 1):

You can downlaod an offline reader for wikipedia.
I use Xowa available here http://xowa.org/home/wiki/Help/Download_XOWA.html
If you download it, open the import pocket, it will point you to a list of available dumps.
I use simplewiki dump wich is around 400mb and has no pictures, just text.
If you want full features, then you choose bigger dumps

There are quite a number of these readers.
You can visit this page for more info
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download